# How to mirror an entire Azure Storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

There are a bunch of ways to manually sync blobs inside an Azure Storage account to a local file-system folder.

One way might be to use [AzCopy to download all blobs of a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#download-blobs-from-blob-storage), and do it for all containers in the account. Of course this can't be scaled, and is only good for one-time operation, or an ad-hoc snapshot.

Another option is to use [Blob events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview), and manually sync each blob once with the local file-system folder. This method is not available in all regions yet, and can't be trusted for long-term operation, since if for any reason they get out of sync, then they remain out of sync.

Is there a way to mirror an entire Azure Storage account, to a local folder?

Comment: Why not use Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: @JoyWang, the way I understand, Azure Storage Explorer is only a tool to access azure storage account and manage it. It doesn't replicate the entire storage to local folders. It only fetches metadata so that we can see what's inside. Just the name of the files, not files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several ways you could follow:

The way of doing this is especially fast if few files has been added/updated/deleted. If many is `added/updated/deleted` it is still fast, but `uploading/downloadig` files to/from the blob will be the main time factor. The algorithm auditor going to describe was developed by me when he was implementing a non-live-editing Window Azure deployment model for Composite C1. 
Refer to [fast recursive local folder to/from azure blob](http://toolheaven.net/post/How-to-do-a-fast-recursive-local-folder-tofrom-azure-blob-storage-synchronization.aspx).

Also, you could install [GoodSync](https://www.goodsync.com/how-to-sync-windows-azure) to sync files between their local and the cloud.

And you will need to install [Gladinet](http://blog.centrestack.com/2011/02/leverage-azure-blob-storage-for-file.html) Cloud Desktop 3.0 and mount your Azure Blob Storage account.When you click on the "**Add New Cloud Sync Folder**" link above, you will see this dialog.
[image]